# Amazon EC2 Force umount Volume does not work

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, large-data-volumes

I am trying to detach an Amazon EC2 Volume, but It get stuck some where, here is the **strace**  output, I tried **fuser -km /mnt/web**  but none of the option is working.

I also tried ls /mnt/,  and deleted the entry from /etc/fstab but it still won't work.

**Strace Output**

```
user@server:~$ sudo strace umount -l /mnt/web
execve("/bin/umount", ["umount", "-l", "/mnt/web"], [/* 14 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xa11000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc411613000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30545, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 30545, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc41160b000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320^\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=155384, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2250504, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc4111cd000
mprotect(0x7fc4111ef000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc4113ef000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x22000) = 0x7fc4113ef000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260Z\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=154648, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2249736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc410fa7000
mprotect(0x7fc410fcc000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc4111cb000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x24000) = 0x7fc4111cb000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1845024, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc41160a000
mmap(NULL, 3953344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc410be1000
mprotect(0x7fc410d9c000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc410f9c000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bb000) = 0x7fc410f9c000
mmap(0x7fc410fa2000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc410fa2000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\26\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18936, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2113968, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc4109dc000
mprotect(0x7fc4109e0000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc410bdf000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7fc410bdf000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0[\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=134296, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2238192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc4107b9000
mprotect(0x7fc4107d9000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc4109d8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1f000) = 0x7fc4109d8000
mmap(0x7fc4109da000, 5872, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc4109da000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\27\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=252032, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc411609000
mmap(NULL, 2347200, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc41057b000
mprotect(0x7fc4105b8000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc4107b7000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3c000) = 0x7fc4107b7000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc410377000
mprotect(0x7fc41037a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fc410579000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fc410579000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc411608000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc411606000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fc411606880) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc410f9c000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc410579000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc4107b7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc4109d8000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc410bdf000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc4113ef000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fc4111cb000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x60f000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fc411615000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fc41160b000, 30545)           = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7fff570957f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7fff570957f0)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(0)                                  = 0xa11000
brk(0xa32000)                           = 0xa32000
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc411612000
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tr"..., 1024) = 374
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fc411612000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1607664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1607664, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fc41147d000
close(3)                                = 0
umask(022)                              = 022
getuid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
readlink("/mnt", 0x7fff57093710, 4096)  = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
readlink("/mnt/web",
```

Comment: raise a ticket to AWS with free service.

Comment: better idea, doing right now, thank you